# collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.contains(x)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to run `collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])` if `if(!collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(x))` returns true.  But I can't seem to get it to work.

I thought it had something to do with optionals, but it doesn't seem to.

I have tried `if let`, `? ?? !` etc.  I have created an optional index_path object and still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Show the actual code as you attempted it. Explain what errors you are getting and where.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an optional `Bool?` as the only member of an if condition. That's because the compiler (with good reason) refuses to infer what it must do when it gets a nil value.

You have several ways to solve this, the important thing is: make sure you're handling the `nil` case the way you intend it to.

From a quick look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems) we learn that `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns `nil` if there are no selected items. In that case your condition must yield a `true` value, because when there are no selected items, *x* is most certainly not contained in the array of selected values.

So, a first solution might be to tell the compiler to treat a nil value from `indexPathsForSelectedItems` as an empty array, which seems quite reasonable: if there are no selected items the array that represents the selected items' indexPath should be empty:

```
// solution 1
if !(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []).contains(x) {
    // select item..
}
```

You have a second way to solve this if you consider that you can't have an optional `Bool?` inside an if condition, but you can always compare a `Bool?` with a `Bool` and thus explicitly tell the compiler the only case among the three you are interested in:

`let isXSelected = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(x)`

1. `isXSelected` returns `nil` → no items selected, i should select x
2. `isXSelected` returns `true` → nothing to do
3. `isXSelected` returns `false` → i should select x

You want to execute the "select x" code in both case 1 and 3, so you want to check if `isXSelected` is not true. In conclusion:

```
// solution 2
if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(x) != true {
    // select item..
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried the empty array and it did not work as expected.  I will your second solution.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem that I posted about.  But did not solve my actual problem as my behavior is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Result of

```
collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(x)
```

is optional bool value: `Bool?`. Swift [does not allow implicit cast](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) to Bool type.  To solve it, create [unwrapping of optional array to non optional array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) `indexPathsForSelectedItems` :

```
if !(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(x) ?? false) {
   //TODO:select item
}
```

Comment: This might not be a correct answer: it seems to me that the OP is trying to check wether x is not among the selectedItems. However, `indexPathsForSelectedItems` can return nil if there are no selected items at all. In that scenario the `if let` condition would skip the nested if and the _select item_ branch of code would not be executed as it should

Comment: to be honest, this could be handled much easier using `?? []`, e.g. `(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []).contains(x)`

Comment: I think it is also good solution but in result you will get double bracket at start and end of a expression: if !((<containt check>)). I do not think that it looks good. But in semantic point of view it is more clear. I think it is more close to discussion about code style and performance of a code.